# My android ui crashes when I collect values from my web server

Tags: android

I have successfully connected my android application to my web service. I can send, collect and update detail on my webservice through my android application. But a simple problem arises, When the application is installed on an android phone. In a case when there is a slow internet network and my application takes too long to collect details from  web server my android app crashes.
Please How do I solve this problem. The class that loads the resources. 
My code is pasted below.

```
public class GetLgsInState extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    private ProgressDialog progressdialog = null;
    Context context;
    private String state = "";

    LGModel[] localgovernments = null;



    public GetLgsInState(Context context,String state){

        this.context = context;
        this.state = state;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressdialog.setMessage("Loading the local government areas in state ...");
        progressdialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> args = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",state));
        JSONHttpClient jsonHttpClient = new JSONHttpClient();
        try{
           localgovernments = jsonHttpClient.Get(RestfulServiceUrl.GetLGInState, args, LGModel[].class);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            Log.i("collection failed","Could not collect");
        }


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (localgovernments.length > 0) {

                    for(LGModel lg : localgovernments){
                        //HashMap<String, String> mapLG = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //mapLG.put(LGModel.LGName,lg.getName());

                        //hospitalList.add(mapLG);

                        lgspinnerAdapter.add(lg.getName());

                        lgspinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }
                else
                {                       
                    //Toast.makeText(context,"No local government for this state",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    errorText.setText("No Local Government entered for this state");
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }           


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
         progressdialog.dismiss();          

    }


}
```

I delibrately alter the webservice so I simulate the possible error that could occur when there is network problem

```
09-09 18:12:05.365: D/AndroidRuntime(380): Shutting down VM
09-09 18:12:05.365: W/dalvikvm(380): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at com.example.medicalrobot.HospitalSearchOption$GetLgsInState$1.run(HospitalSearchOption.java:203)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-09 18:12:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(380):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 18:12:08.245: I/Process(380): Sending signal. PID: 380 SIG: 9
09-09 18:12:09.694: I/dalvikvm(409): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onHoverEvent
09-09 18:12:09.694: W/dalvikvm(409): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4386: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
09-09 18:12:09.694: D/dalvikvm(409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
09-09 18:12:09.694: D/dalvikvm(409): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
09-09 18:12:09.715: I/dalvikvm(409): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getAlpha
09-09 18:12:09.715: W/dalvikvm(409): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3088: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
09-09 18:12:09.715: D/dalvikvm(409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
```

Comment: The application works fine. But when there is a network issue connecting to the web service the app crashes. So I delibrately alter the webservice url so you can see what would be generated in log cat.

Comment: when http request fails for any reason your localgovernments will be null, so checking this condition localgovernments.length>0 will cause your app to crash.

Comment: "The application works fine." No it doesn't, or you wouldn't be here. Please refer to the `AsyncTask` documentation to understand how to use it properly; there's no reason to resort to `runOnUiThread`. Second, if you *know* the service access failed, don't attempt to access broken or missing data.

Comment: Yeah thanks I am checking it (Moh.Sukhni). You right that is the real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable object `localgovernments` may be receiving null from web-service output

check if it is null

```
if (localgovernments!=null){
 if (localgovernments.length > 0) {

                    for(LGModel lg : localgovernments){
                        //HashMap<String, String> mapLG = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //mapLG.put(LGModel.LGName,lg.getName());

                        //hospitalList.add(mapLG);

                        lgspinnerAdapter.add(lg.getName());

                        lgspinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
}
```

Comment: check it if it helps rate it

Comment: Woow problem as been solved. My application no longer crashers tanks to you all that contributed. I am more than greatful

Comment: Yes you must implement else portion if it is null